# python web extraction of iframe (ajax ) content

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am working on python web scraping

The web page is polluted using iframe and the content is filled by ajax(jquery)

I have tried using src of iframe(using lxml,.) but its of no use

How can i extract the content of the iframe using python modules

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Selenium will do the job for you. Look at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Answer (score 1):

Splinter (http://splinter.cobrateam.info - uses selenium) makes browsing iframe elements easy. At least as long iframe tag has id attribute.